# Узнать позицию курсора в редакторе TinyMce

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Пишу плагин для редактора TinyMce. В документации к написанию плагинов в примере используется метод `editor.insertContent(content);` Если вызвать этот метод - в контент на позицию курсора вставится определенный контент. Значит данный объект `editor` каким-то образом знает позицию курсора в документе. А как мне просто узнать позицию курсора? Никто не сталкивался?

P.S. Пробовал console.log(editor); и поискать там методы - не нашёл

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот здесь есть решение данного вопроса: https://drujoopress.wordpress.com/2014/08/06/find-cursor-position-inside-tinymce-editor/

```
var ed = tinyMCE.get('TXT_AREA_ID');     // get editor instance
var range = ed.selection.getRng().startOffset;     // get range

alert(range);
```